# Split AttributeError, "'str' object has no attribute 'spilt'"

Tags: python, module, casting, python-module

text is shown below, I've searched high and low for the solution, but can't find anything. any help is appreciated

```
import random
from aiohttp import request
from aiohttp import web
from random import randint

response = request.__get__('https://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text%2Fplain')

r = request.__get__(response)
dootdoot = r

indivial_words = str(dootdoot).spilt()
random_number = randint(0, len(indivial_words))

print(indivial_words[random_number] + str(random_number))
```

I've looked on this site, and a few others, and tried typecasting in the code, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled `split`.

```
indivial_words = str(dootdoot).split() # instead of .spilt()
```